# Google Cloud docker image file getting deleted

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I am running a docker image for Juypter and tensorboard. The data seem to get deleted everytime the VM instance is stopped is there away to stop this from happening i could find anything on the web that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Most Likely you are not persisting the data. Please share your docker run command and more information about the VM you are using like OS, type, etc.

Comment: The docker run is: docker pull lspvic/tensorboard-notebook
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 lspvic/tensorboard-notebook. I am using Container-Optimized OS 86-15053.0

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You are not persisting your data.

Docker containers does not persist data out of the box, you need to explicity tell docker to persist any data created inside the container when the container is deleted.

You can read more at [Use volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) page at Docker documentation.

If you want to persist data you need to do the next steps:

1. Create a local volume inside the VM where you want to persist data. This command should be executed on the GCE instance

`mkdir -p /opt/data/jupyterdata`

2. Set the correct ownership of the folder to the user id that the user inside your container uses. For example, let's imagine that your container `lspvic/tensorboard-notebook` run the application using the user *tensorflow* with  the UID 1500. So you need to set the ownership of your folder to the UID 1500:

`chown 1500:1500 /opt/data/jupyterdata -R`

3. Modify your docker run command to mount the local directory as a volume inside the container. For example, lets imagine that inside your container you want to save the files at /var/lib/jupyter (this is an example), you will need to modify the docker run command as follows:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 \
-v /opt/data/jupyterdata:/var/lib/jupyter:Z \
lspvic/tensorboard-notebook
```

NOTE: the `:Z` parameter is needed to avoid [SELINUX issues](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-the-selinux-label)

With this steps now your data saved on folder `/var/lib/jupyter` inside the container will be saved on `/opt/data/jupyterdata` inside the VM so no more data loss.

Comment: Thanks very much i will give this a go.

Comment: I get an error message when I try to run this command. mkdir -o /opt/data/jupyterdata. Als, I have noticed that if i connect to the command prompt on the Google VM itis different when i run the docker image shouldn't both be the same? Thanks for your help.

Comment: My bad, is `mkdir -p`

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I am trying to docker command to mount the drive but I get the error message lspvic/tensorboard-notebook' returned a non-zero code: 2. Any idea please? Can i stick all of the code in docker file then run it? Thanks for your help.